# Issue with wp_get_attachment_url() function for multisite

Tags: multisite, attachments

I have a WordPress site and I created the multisite network by following the below URL

https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

And I am trying to upload files from frontend uploader form. The image is being uploaded to the correct path but the function `wp_get_attachment_url($attachment_id)` is returning me wrong URL like bellow where site id is being included twice in the URL.

http://network.v1.blog.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/sites/2/2019/01/15.jpg

It should be

http://network.v1.blog.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2019/01/15.jpg

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What’s your code for uploading the image?

Comment: How you get the var `$attachment_id?

Comment: @bueltge assume $attachment_id = 4; I didn't post the full code.